# Given a bootstrap input group with a dropdown menu. How to trigger a different filter depending of the current selected <a>

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

SO basically right now I have a simple input group which is made to trigger a filter in my angular app. (sizeFilter)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Filter by size</span>
    </div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="sizeInput" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Large"
        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
</div>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">hash</th>
            <th scope="col">size</th>
            <th scope="col">time</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody *ngFor="let data  of json | sizeFilter : sizeInput"> <-- THis is there my filter is right now
        <tr>
            <td (click)="onUpdateClick(data.hash , data.size, data.time)" class="hHover"
                title="Click to update the data">{{data.hash}}</td>
            <td>{{data.size}}</td>
            <td>{{data.time}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onDeleteClick(data.hash)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I want to create another filter, and add a dropdown menu to the input group . So I can select the filter that I want to use. For example the current one is only for size. But maybe I want to filter by other paramenter , time for example.

I was looking at this input group with a dropdown menu

```
    <div class="input-group mt-3 mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Filter1</a> <--- THis is where I would want to trigger some filters depending of the selection
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Filter2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Filter3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

But how AM i supposed to trigger the ngModel and specify the trigger I want to use with an  element?

Comment: Is `sizeFilter : sizeInput` the pipe that you are using to filter? Well, first change this `[(ngModel)]=sizeInput` to this `[(ngModel)]="sizeInput"` You may need to write another pipe to achieve that

Comment: @sudo_kaizen thats a fair point , I will . I know that I need another pipe, but how do i select which one to use then? SInce I will have my sizeFIlter , but what if I want to use for example hashFIlter (a new pipe)

Comment: Well, then this line `<tbody *ngFor="let data  of json | sizeFilter : sizeInput">` will become `<tbody *ngFor="let data  of json | sizeFilter : sizeInput | hashFIlter: hashInput">` Both will be applied by default and if you modify `sizeInput` and `hashInput` both will be applied. THerefore, in the implementation of your pipes (I mean your pipe.ts,) return all values in the array if there is no input for `sizeInput` and `hashInput`

Comment: @sudo_kaizen thanks, I wasnt aware of the possibility of using different filters at a time. But... will it allow me to select between the filter that i want to apply depending of what is selected in the dropdown? Or will it apply both by default?

Comment: I have answered your question in my earlier comment. What you need to know now is that the `sizeFilter` pipe will take precedence over the `hashFIlter` because `sizeFilter` appeaars before `hashFIlter` in the template